# What is the path to the "System.Text.Json"?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, system.text.json

I updated yesterday morning to the latest versions of Xamarin and Xcode. I am now posed with this error when loading the iOS project: "Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51". Where can I find it? It not in "C:\Users\username.nuget\packages".

[image: Error Message]

Additionally, Output stated:

> 2>_CompileToNative:
> 2>  [xma]: Uploading 'Sentry.iOS.exe' (36/36 KB) 100.00%...
> 2>  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/marcgeorge/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Sentry.iOS/44d8d7434e850748f5ee25da92692acc/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/response-file.rsp
> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): warning MT0136: Cannot find the assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' referenced from '/Users/marcgeorge/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Sentry.iOS/44d8d7434e850748f5ee25da92692acc/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll'.
> 2>
> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(884,3): error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

[image]

It appears that the problem is with Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets which needs to located the Json library.

Comment: Not even sure `System.Text.Json` works on Xamarin.IOS, see [System.Text.Json Serializer does not appear to work on Xamarin iOS #31326](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31326).

Comment: What code do you used for? You could try to reinstall the `System.Text.Json` from the GitHub.https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the Nugget as suggested by @Wendy resolved the issue.